# Will Apple reject cocos2D game if it does not fit iPhone 5 screen?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, iphone-5

In two days I will upload Cocos2D game for iPhone to itunesconnect for review. Now this game does not support iPhone 5 resolution, but does support both iPhone 4S and iPhone 3GS. Will Apple reject this app for absence of compatibility for iPhone 5 or (maybe, I don't know now) incorrect behavior of cocos2d's sprites or so? I will correct that in the first patch, but now I need to release the game immediately, because game does not belong to me and customer want it be released as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. In the same way Apple doesn't reject iPhone apps that don't support iPad resolution.

Comment: but iPad is another category, since iPhone is the same... however, thanks!

Comment: r u sure i can still get apps without new resolution supported approved? that will ease tons of problem.

Comment: @OMGPOP my game has been released on October 1st without any problems, so LearnCocos2D was right

Answer (score 1):

An older iOS app running on iOS 6 will automatically be letter-boxed (with black spaces at the top and bottom of the screen), so you don't have to worry about the screen layout. There are a lot of other things in iOS 6 that may break an older app, however, so you'll definitely want to at least run the app on the iOS 6 4-inch screen simulator (and the sim won't catch all the potential problems).

Comment: running the game on iOS 6 and running one on iPhone 5 are different things, I've already fix bugs with iOS 6, but I have no time for adding support for iPhone 5 resolution. Thanks for tip for black spaces

Answer (score 1):

YES.

From 1st May 2013, Apple reject all app if iPhone 5 is not supported. iPhone HD is must but not iPad HD. All you need to do is just upload iPad HD image in screenShot.

Comment: interesting... Could you provide links to where that was stated?

Comment: iPhone5 support is must, iPad HD..just some people experimented and realised that apple still approve if iPad hd is not supported..even one of my last game approved with just iPad sd :)